# Which AWS service would you suggest for storing game data?

Tags: database, rest, amazon-web-services

I'm making a game that requires a database that has 2 tables. The database will have to be reached through an api endpoint. Table 1 is usernames and passwords. Table 2 is usernames and scores. I need the following methods:

1. Create new user and password (must be unique) in table 1.
2. Create or update score if exists in table 2.
3. Get a specific username and score and rank.
4. Get top 10 scores and usernames.
5. Get any number of usernames and scores from a passed in list of usernames.

I was trying to make this work with DynamoDB and Lambda functions but it doesn't appear to have this flexibility in getting exactly what I want. I would have to scan the whole table of names and then find the top 10 which is a lot of processing. Any other suggestions?

I'm not sure how many users there will be but assume there will be a lot. Cost is a factor so cheapest solution that will work is the best.

Answer (score 1):

For authentication: [Amazon Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html)

For storage: Amazon DynamoDB

Populate scores into two tables.

**Table 1: By user and game**

- Partition key: User ID + Game ID
- Sort key: Game # (unique reference to instance of game played)

Use this table when retrieving games played for a specific user.

**Table 2: By game and score**

- Partition key: Game ID
- Sort key: Score

Use this table when retrieving High Scores for a given game (sort by Score descending).

Comment: I tried with DynamoDB. The problem i found is that DynamoDB cant handle passing in a parameter like "username":["usr1","user2"..."usrx"]. It also doesnt seem to be able to determine the top 10 scores unless i scan the whole table and find them myself, which is wayyy to costly.

Comment: You can have a GSI with sort key for score so that you can query the users in score order to find the top scorers.

Comment: @Ashan Im not sure what GSI is but the table that i previously tried on with dynamoDB was set us as score with a sort key. Since it was declared as a sort key, it because a required parameter. That meant that if i wanted to Update a users score, i needed to know the existing score for that user and pass it in as the score parameter. That seemed like too much work and was an extra db call. I believe that the sorting also didnt work because I did not have a value to pass in for score.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but other people might be able to verify and suggest improvements.